# How to make sure I download all data on Heroku before closing the account?

Tags: heroku, backup, download

I do not understand the structure on Heroku (I'm not a programmer). How can I download apps, databases before closing the account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you shouldn't need to [download you apps from Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app):

> A Heroku app’s Git repository is intended for deployment purposes only. Cloning from this repository is not officially supported as a feature and should be attempted only as a last resort. **Do not** use this repository as your app’s canonical “origin” repository. Instead, use your own Git server or a version control service such as GitHub.

Even if you're not using GitHub or similar each of your developers should have a copy of the application. There's no way to "develop live" on Heroku, so there must be at least one other copy of each application (unless they've been deleted).

As far as databases go, if you're using Heroku Postgres you can [download a copy of your database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#export) using `heroku pg:backups:capture` followed by `heroku pg:backups:download`, as documented. Other database addons have different needs.

Your best bet to make sure you have everything is to spin your application up somewhere else and make sure it works. If you have a test suite, run it. Validating data will be tricky, but you can check some simple metrics like the number and names of tables, the number of records in each table, making sure you can log in with any accounts you have and that their application-facing data looks reasonable, etc.